# How to call Nodejs api in the python code?

Tags: python, node.js, api

I am automating the functionality which is written in Nodejs,and gives a graphical view when the web page is called. I need to retrieve the contents of webpage in a file. All this code will be written in python. How can I call the web page api in the python code so that I get all the contents in a file.

Comment: You will have to use a framework for this. I would suggest flask, hit those APIs directly using flask.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python Requests Module:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://example.com')
print(response.text)
```

[To learn more](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Comment: Is this what you are seeking?